# Beatbox: Select all query

Tags: salesforce, beatbox

In place of giving column names in service.query I want to retrieve all the columns of a custom object or may be Accounts. Any idea on how to do it with beatbox API?

Comment: What you mean by "all columns"? For example Contact object has a column "Name" that is usually configured to be the concatenated FirstName and LastName. Such redundant columns are not a part of Salesforce backup and probably you don't want them. Some columns are a roll-up summary of child objects and don't depend on the current row at all. Maybe you are interested only in "updateable" columns or "createable" columns or both and a few system fields. // Please look at my answer to [your older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43625053/448474) and write a short comment if you will not accept.

Comment: Thanks hynecker for the solution of delete items from an object. However here i wanted to try 'select * ' kind of functionality through beatbox. Superfell's solution was bang on. It served the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call describeSObject so that you can collect up all the field names, then generate them into your query.